# How do you edit your name in War of the Roses?

Tags: war-of-the-roses

I can't find where the user name gets set. How do I change it from the default?

Comment: I beleive it just utilizes your Steam name, but I'm unsure how the name is determined in the non-Steam version (or whether there is a non-Steam version, for that matter)

Answer (score 1):

You have to buy the full version of the game in order for you to change the name settings. Go to "Manage Soldier" and you have the option of changing your name. Name changes can only occur though every 60 days.